# Cannot set the values of struct variable in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity

when i am trying to initialize the values for array of struct variable i am not
able do it

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

contract shop{
    struct student{
        string name;
        uint roll;
    }
    student[] public s;
    function setstudent() public{
        s[0].name = "sam";
        s[0].roll = 98246;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign into a non-existing index of the array.

For creating a new item (i.e. increasing the array size), use the `push()` function.

```
s.push(
    student("sam", 98246)
);
```